# sparse and dense array python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

In Python, I'd like a sparse COO matrix whose values are dense matrices. In other words, a 4-dimensional array which is sparse along the first two axes.

I'm currently using [sparse.COO](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/sparse.COO.html) to represent sparse arrays. These store sparse arrays in coordinate format, for example,

```
[[ 1 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 1 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 0 ]
 [ 0 0 1 ]]
```

would be stored as a list of nonzero values and their coordinates, something like

```
[((0, 0), 1), ((2, 1), 1), ((5, 2), 1)]
```

But there does not seem to be a way to have some axes be dense while others are sparse, e.g. store

```
[[[ 1 2 ]
  [ 3 4 ]]

 [[ 0 0 ]
  [ 0 0 ]]]
```

in a way that indicates that only the index 0 entry along the first axis is nonzero, like

```
[(0,
 [[ 1 2 ]
  [ 3 4 ]])]
```

**How would I do this?** Ideally with a class which does not violate the `numpy.ndarray` broadcasting and indexing interface.

Comment: While it's possible to make a `coo` with non-numeric data values, you can't do anything with it.  Conversion to `csr` for math will raise some sort of error; even `to_array()` to display will give an error.  `coo` can't do indexing; and none of the `scipy` formats can do `ndarray` broadcasting.  They aren't a `ndarray` subclass.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` is built on ideas developed years ago to solve large sparse linear equation systems.  It isn't a general purpose data storage system.

Comment: I'm not using ```scipy.sparse``` explicitly, although the ```sparse``` package does use it under the hood. And to be clear, I'm not asking how to do what I want with a specific class; I'm asking if there is another class (potentially not in a scipy library) which does what I want.